# A shorter, more formal word for "as you go" or "along the way"

Tags: synonyms

We have common phrasing such as “pay as you go” or “invent along the way”.

Is there a more formal and specific word for this concept of a verb’s action continuing or repeating over time?

Comment: continuing:  *continual*  Repeating over time: *habitual or recurring, or periodic*

Comment: Specific to what? paying or inventing? The adverb progressively could work.

Comment: @Jim “continual” is close, but does not allow for the interruptions or infrequency implied by my examples. Both “recurring” & “periodic” are close as well, but similarly have the problem of supporting regular or rigid frequency. I am looking for a sense that is less definite.

Comment: @Zebrafish The word “progressively” means reaching stages, building on one another. My meaning is not about building up but about whatever may come.

Comment: @BasilBourque - Perhaps if you told us your actual situation we could come up with the right word. As it is, we don’t have enough information and we are just shooting in the dark.

Comment: How about *on an **as needed** basis*?

Comment: @Jim My actual situation is quite close to my examples. To test any proposed word, replace "as you go" or "along the way" in my examples.

Comment: I have never heard of “invent along the way”  is it more along the lines of flying by the seat of your pants? Or jury rigging? Or crossing that bridge when you get to it?

Comment: @Jim I meant it as a common phrasing "along the way", not a specific idiom. "As we travel across the country, we’ll take time to smell the roses along the way.” “As I lay the bricks for this garden wall, along the way I want you to check the level line.”

Comment: How about ***enroute***?

Comment: Does “intermittently” fit the bill?

Answer (score 2):

**consecutive**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/consecutive)

> one after the other

As in:

*He was asked to pay **consecutively** as he passed each station.*

Consecutive comes from the Latin consecutus, meaning "following closely" with no gap.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but “consecutively” means definite points along the way, whereas I am looking for something more indefinite. Both my examples, “pay as you go” or “invent along the way”, are more open-ended, allowing for happenstance, and where the events along the way are not building upon one another.